# Minecraft Wiki Migration - Link changes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, minecraft, hyperlinks

The Minecraft wiki's management has moved from Fandom (https://minecraft.gamepedia.com) to an independent wiki (https://minecraft.wiki) and it's likely going to become out of date.

Is it possible, to change all the links from:

- https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/<page>
- https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/wiki/<page>
- https://minecraft.wikia.com/<page>
- https://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/<page>
- https://minecraft.fandom.com/<page>
- https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/<page>
- https://minecraftwiki.net/<page>
- https://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/<page>
- https://www.minecraftwiki.net/<page>
- https://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/<page>
- <s>https://minepedia.net/<page></s>*

to:

- https://minecraft.wiki/w/<page>

If a page is not existing above, it is likely to have already been deleted in Fandom as well since the fork is only a few days old.

*not in Fandom control, but may have been used historically.

Comment: I think there is a Meta SE post about mass re-routing URLs. SE staff have a tool that they can use to do this. So we will need their help!

Comment: You also need //www.minecraftwiki.net/ in your list of source links. There are [864 posts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2F%2Fwww.minecraftwiki.net%2F%22) with www. prefixing and only [15 posts without](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2F%2Fminecraftwiki.net%2F%22)

Comment: If we can get the exact mapping nailed down, this is a good candidate for the tool the SE staff uses. Once we are certain we have all the links that will need to be updated, a mod can add the status-review tag to this question and an SE staff can fix them all for us in one shot

Comment: Hey CM or Dev that handles this - This also affects Tag Wikis - eg [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/minecraft-java-edition/info) - hopefully whatever tool you use to update Q&A can also be run on wikis :)

Comment: Actually, Java and Bedrock are both covered by the MC Wiki, so it's not only [tag:minecraft-java-edition] but also [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition], [tag:minecraft-commands], [tag:minecraft-java-edition-server] and [tag:minecraft-redstone]... Basically anything with the word "minecraft" in it (except the modded stuffs, unless it's referencing a Vanilla game item).

Answer (score 12):

There appears to be [at least 3482 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/1787178/minecraft-wiki-migration-post-estimates-https-gaming-meta-stackexchange-com-q) (15 of which are tag wikis) which contain one of these domains:

- `//minecraft.gamepedia.com/`
- `//minecraft.fandom.com/`
- `//minecraftwiki.net/`
- `//www.minecraftwiki.net/`

The URL remapping tool works using simple find and replace. This makes something like this somewhat tricky compared with a regular expression based replacement since **every single** pattern needs to be specified.

[A RegEx solution](https://regex101.com/r/WeUt3K/1) could easily to handle this remapping, particularly around the fact that both `/<path>` and `/wiki/<path>` both need to map to `/w/<path>`.

Given the limitations, the most direct approach would be to do the following remappings in order:

|  | Source | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/wiki/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 2 | https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/wiki/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 3 | http://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 4 | https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 5 | http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 6 | https://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 7 | http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 8 | https://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 9 | http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 10 | https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 11 | http://minecraft.fandom.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 12 | https://minecraft.fandom.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 13 | http://minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 14 | https://minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 15 | http://www.minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 16 | https://www.minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |

The benefit of this approach is that this will both update the URLs to the new domain and update the protocol from http:// to https:// for all links. As opposed to, say, remapping `//minecraft.gamepedia.com/` to `//minecraft.wiki/w/` which wouldn't update the protocol. And, yes, there are [a good amount of http:// links that could use some updating](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fminecraft.gamepedia.com%2F%22).

---

Alternatively, we could do a smaller number of remappings:

|  | Source | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 2 | https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 3 | http://minecraft.fandom.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 4 | https://minecraft.fandom.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 5 | http://minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 6 | https://minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 7 | http://www.minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 8 | https://www.minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |

Doing the domain mappings before mapping away the `//site/wiki/` links will cause issues with, for example, [the 362 posts with links that start with https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fminecraft.fandom.com%2Fwiki%2F%22)
which will end up being rewritten as `https://minecraft.wiki/w/wiki/<path>` instead
of `https://minecraft.wiki/w/<path>`.

But this could be fixed by remapping `/w/wiki/` to just `/w/`:

| Source | Destination |
| --- | --- |
| https://minecraft.wiki/w/wiki/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |

This approach would be 9 remappings instead of 16

|  | Source | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 2 | https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 3 | http://minecraft.fandom.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 4 | https://minecraft.fandom.com/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 5 | http://minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 6 | https://minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 7 | http://www.minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 8 | https://www.minecraftwiki.net/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |
| 9 | https://minecraft.wiki/w/wiki/ | https://minecraft.wiki/w/ |

Comment: How did other language links work back when it was Gamepedia? If it was `minecraft.gamepedia.com/de/foo` and any of these links were used (possible, because e.g. the German wiki has a really good pause/main menu that you can click through), then this would break those links, since no other languages were migrated yet.

Comment: Also something to consider is web.archive.org. I personally use the wiki's own history for all my archive links, but maybe someone uses that instead. (The history links should just work: `?oldid=2316368`)

Comment: @FabianRöling given that this is an English language site it doesn't seem like there would be very many non-English links. We can always test for those urls if you know what they are but your example of `minecraft.gamepedia.com/de/` gives [0 results](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22minecraft.gamepedia.com%2Fde%2F%22).

Comment: I checked my browser history, but found no results, either, so I don't know what the format was.

Comment: Hm, what about `https*:(\/\/|\\\\)(www\.)*minecraft\S*(wiki|fandom|gamepedia|wikia)\S*(\/|\\)`?

Comment: The Regex is mostly just demonstrative since their tool cannot use Regex. That's why there are Source Destination tables for the simple find-replace that *is* supported @aytimothy I would also suggest against that pattern which would match a whole lot of different stuff, for example, `httpssss://www.www.www.minecraft.this.is.really.matching.a.lot.of....stuff...wiki....\\\\/\/\\/ ` matches

Answer (score 5):

We have replaced the following 5 links with https://minecraft.wiki/w/.   There were over 50 instances of each of these links across the site, which is the threshold for our bulk replacement tool.

- http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/
- http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/
- http://www.minecraftwiki.net/index.php/
- https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/
- https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/

There was a sixth link which we planned to bulk replace (http://www.minecraftwiki.net/), but did not because most of the instances were images which don't appear to work on the new url.

The other links listed in the question and answer above each had under 50 occurrences. We encourage the community to work together to replace the remaining links manually, if it is a priority.

Comment: Thanks Sasha! Much appreciated 

Comment: @Sasha Unless I’m missing something, this appears to have been not completely executed. A couple counterexamples out of the 4-figure count reported by the query linked above: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/212228/308792 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/165826/308792

Comment: @Micha sorry, can you explain the problem you are seeing a bit more in depth?

Comment: @Sasha It appears that some links (such as the ones in the posts I linked) got missed by the bulk replacement.

Comment: @Micha thanks for explaining, I will look into this.

Comment: @Micha we did some checks and found a few areas where links were missed. This should be resolved now but please let us know if you notice anything else!